# Log a Stream of text

Tags: elixir

I have an Elixir app where I spawn an external process using [`Porcelain`](https://github.com/alco/porcelain). The spawned process' STDOUT is available to me as stream of text as `proc.out` (in the form of `#Function<59.89908360/2 in Stream.unfold/2>`).

I'm able to print the stream's content line by line using `IO.stream/2` but I would explicitly like to do it using `Logger.info`. This is what it currently looks like:

```
proc = Porcelain.spawn("node", ["/path/to/node/server.js"], [out: :stream])
stream = proc.out
Enum.into(stream, IO.stream(:stdio, :line))
```

I've currently tried:

- `[out: Logger.info]`
- `Enum.into(proc.out, Logger.info)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enum.map/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) and [`Enum.each/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#each/2) both solve my problem by iterating over the stream lines and applying `Logger.info`. But as [@dogbert pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819955/log-a-stream-of-text/39820079?noredirect=1#comment66930424_39820079), `each` might be faster and better suited in this case:

```
Enum.each(stream, &Logger.info/1)
```

Comment: `Enum.each` might be a bit faster and more idiomatic since you're not going to use the return value of `Logger.info/1`.

Comment: Thanks @dogbert. I'll use that.